# Popen не запускает процесс

Tags: php, exec

Добрый день!
Есть функция(из комментов на php.net)

```
function execInBackground($cmd) { 
  if (substr(php_uname(), 0, 7) == "Windows"){ 
    pclose(popen('start /B '.$cmd, "r"));  
  } 
  else { 
    exec($cmd . " > /dev/null &");   
  } 
}
```

Когда пытаюсь с ее помощью запустить скрипт на выполнение, то ничего не происходит:

```
$cmd = "php ..\runffmpeg.php";
execInBackground($cmd);
```

В то же время, если запускаю другую команду, то все работает:

```
$cmd = 'ffmpeg -i video_in.mp4 video_out.avi';
execInBackground($cmd);
```

Или если выполняю через команду exec, то все тоже хорошо:

```
exec("php ..\runffmpeg.php");
```

Выходит, что pclose(popen('start /B php ..\runffmpeg.php', "r"));  не выполняет команду. В чем может быть проблема? У меня windows 7 и php 5.4.7

Comment: Странно, что exec работает. Потому как `\r` -- возврат каретки. Вот если бы Вы написали `"php \\runffmpeg.php"` ...

Answer (score 1):

Возможно все дело в слешах? Может их надо проэкранировать?
Например так:

```
$cmd = "php ..\\runffmpeg.php";
execInBackground($cmd);
```