# Составить команду для запуска в фоне без ожидания

Tags: php

Есть команда

> exec("php -f 3.php");

При выполнении получается так что скрипт ожидает пока исполнится другой запущенный этой командой скрипт.Как сделать так чтобы клиент не ждал скрипта и получил известие что скрипт выполняется...

Comment: передайте другой текстовый файл который будет в роли консоли ввода

Comment: @Saidolim Расскажите,пожалуйста, подробнее.Желательно в ответ

Comment: Такой вопрос уже был, если коротко: `exec('some_command > /dev/null 2>&1 &')`

Comment: @ВОРОН что-то не работает данный вариант `exec('php -f E:/OpenServer/domains/admin/3.php > /dev/null 2>&1 &');`

Comment: ну так то винда, потому и не работает `/dev/null` на линуксе, для винды по-другому запускать надо. Если винда у вас только для разработки, а выкладывать будете на линукс - забейте на винду и смотрите сразу на линуксе. UPD: неработает, т.к. `command &` запустит в фоне только на линуксе

Comment: Тогда вопрос решен:)

Comment: На всякий случай: [здесь](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/225179/5079) в самом вопросе приведен пример как надо запускать процесс в фоне, там правда у автора проблема какая-то была, но возможно причина указана в комментах

Comment: @МихаилХалупов если у вас есть решение - запостите его как ответ. ответы к комментах, и прочие "разобрался, всем спасибо" - зло :)

Comment: @МихаилХалупов, это не вопрос из серии "сессии блокируют выполнение скриптов php"?

Comment: @Visman Нет.Винда виновата

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Пишу свое решение. Есть некоторые неточности, поправьте.

Работает только под Linux, запускать для Windows нужно по-другому (этого я и не учёл).

Шаблон для запуска чего-то в фоне :(спасибо *ВОРОНУ*)

> exec('some_command > /dev/null 2>&1 &') - где **/dev/null** выкидывает в мусорку,а говорит *&* о  работе в фоне

Для запуска файла в фоне нужно сделать так:

> exec('php -f **путь где находится скрипт** > /dev/null 2>&1 &')

Comment: Windows: shell_exec('php -f путь где находится скрипт >NUL')